# error: Cannot fetch linaro-swg/arm-trusted-firmware.git

Tags: git

I'm trying to build OP-TEE on linux Ubuntu OS by following this procedure https://optee.readthedocs.io/building/gits/build.html#get-and-build-the-solution

In step 3, with the command "$ repo sync -j4 --no-clone-bundle", there is error message as follows:

error: Cannot fetch linaro-swg/arm-trusted-firmware.git (GitError: --force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local work tree. If you're comfortable with the possibility of losing the work tree's git metadata, use `repo sync --force-sync arm-trusted-firmware` to proceed.)
Exception in thread Thread-9:

What can I do to fetch linaro-swg/arm-trusted-firmware.git?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said on [H. Mijail's Blog](http://hmijailblog.blogspot.com/), in [repo sync --force-sync overwrites your existing repository!](http://hmijailblog.blogspot.com/2016/06/repo-sync-force-sync-overwrites-your.html):

> Looks like repo keeps track of the repositories that it has init'ed.
>   So if you created a repository independently of repo, and then add an entry for that existing repository to the repo manifest, repo sync will choke and present you with the message:
>
> ```
> error.GitError: --force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local work tree. If you're comfortable with the possibility of losing the work tree's git metadata, use `repo sync --force-sync mydirectory` to proceed.
> ```
>
> Turns out that "git metadata" means the whole `.git` directory inside mydirectory.
>   So, any branch, any stash, anything in your existing local repository will be destroyed. No recourse to reflog, either!
>
> Once  you have run `repo --force-sync`, the repository will be accepted by repo on further repo sync calls.
>
> An alternative to using `--force-sync` might have been to use `--force-break` (or simply `-f`), which just goes on when any directory fails to sync.
>   But I didn't try, and I don't know how that would even make sense if we assume that repo doesn't go into a directory it didn't create.

In any case... do a backup first of your local repo!